# How to display a thumbnail of custom file in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows

**Background**: I've developed an application (C#/WPF) that can read and render some 3D files.

I would like to know how to display a thumbnail of the actual 3D in Windows (7) Explorer:

[image]

Information I have found so far is messy and inconclusive.

Some posts here point at `Windows API Code Pack` for this task but I have not found any example performing it. Others suggest to work with a `Shell Extension`. I assume that those thumbnails are stored in `Thumbs.db` file inside of some folders, it would be ideal to be able to modify it in order to include my custom thumbnails.

[In this post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289172(v=vs.71).aspx) it is explained how to create a thumbnail of an Office document using C++ or Visual Basic. I'm not sure if this is what I need and I actually do not understand how this thumbnail generation thing works.

Any hint or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is another [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) pointing to a sample using the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK)..